# I co-signed on an apartment for a now ex-boyfriend who refuses to pay. What can I do?

Tags: rent, debt-collection, co-sign, liability

I co-signed on an apartment with my ex-boyfriend when I was 18 and he was 21. We broke up.

I am now 26 and it has been in collections for years. He refuses to help pay the debt. I am now stuck with the bills for the apartment and not in the financial situation to pay it off. He refuses to pay anything and I am not able to locate him.

What can be done in this situation? Is he liable for the rent? And how am I able to get him to pay?

Comment: Questions for you: What does your contract say? Are you "liable in solidarity", that would mean that your rent collector can collect hte rent from you and you have to see yourself for your ex-partner to pay you back. Second: Do you know where he lives? Do you know his phone number, anything? In this case you might be able to locate him.

Comment: This sounds horrible.  Can you explain, **how long did you in fact both live in the apartment?**  IE was it 1 month, 1 year, or until recently?

Comment: And what is the total, absolute, amount owing?

Comment: Does your jurisdiction allow you to "sue him out" of the lease, maybe in his absence, if he isn't to be found? You'd still be stuck with the rent, but would be free to end the lease on your terms. You might still have to pay any open debts, but after that you might be free.

Comment: You should also include the tag of your country, which is important to get legal advice.

Comment: Do you mean you signed a lease? Or you purchased this apartment?

Comment: A couple of years a friend of my wife asked me to co-sign an apartment. My answer was "I would not even do that even for family". The question is that as a co-signer I have far less protection than the debtor and they come after me ªfirstª because it is simply... *easier*. I also told my wife I want to sleep peacefully in the next 10-20 years. As for co-signing with family, it is even a worse idea. Instead of one house with problems, two houses will have problems.

Comment: @LucasRaphaelPianegonda I don't think SE gives legal advice though.

Comment: Purchase or lease? Are you still living in the apartment? If not, who's living in it? Is it rentable? Is it sublettable? Does the potential rent exceed the monthly upkeep?

Answer (score 152):

Advice based on USA style system.

### Do not pay it.  Do not talk to the creditor.

What you have is old debt.  The debt is not still accumulating, it has stopped some years ago, and now, **the debt is slowly aging out**.

After 7 years, it falls off your credit report.

After some shorter amount of time, 2-6 years typically, it will become "time-barred" because it is beyond the *statute of limitations* for lawsuits in your state.

### If you pay on, or acknowledge the debt, the clocks restart.

*So don't flipping do that*.

"Acknowledge" typically means in writing.  Paying on a debt is the sincerest way to acknowledge a debt. Which is why we are not doing that.

Paying the debt fully.... restarts the clock and gives you 7 years of bad luck on your credit report.

***Wait, what?*** Paying on a debt makes my credit worse, and not paying on it makes my credit better!?? *What madness is this?* The credit industry's madness.  You signed onto this when you chose to do business with them by cosigning. It's not moral... but *their house, their rules*.

### You have insolvency armor

Since you don't have any money (so you say), they probably will not sue you.  Generally it is not worth suing over an amount below $5000-10,000 because if the "debtor" chooses to put up a smart fight, *their* legal expenses can be more than they can ever hope to recover.   But that assumes a solvent opponent, **if you're also broke**, then they can't get blood from a stone, and any legal expenses are a total loss.

More likely than not, they are getting "antsy" because they can read a calendar and can see the *Statute of Limitations* is about to expire.  They're getting more and more desperate to get you to "acknowledge the debt" so they can restart the clock. **And this works**.  Citizens are finance-stupid to begin with, and can easily be whipped into a blind panic where they will do *anything* if they think that'll make the phone stop ringing.

You have all the power here, don't blow it.

### But... The debt!

Again, **their house, their rules**.

Anyway, it's not like they're only calling you. *They're calling him, too*, because he is the main debtor. **So forget any thought of suing your ex-boyfriend**, because if these experienced collectors can't get any blood out of that stone, you sure can't!  A lawsuit from you on him would just muddy the water, and worse, would ***acknowledge the debt***, which you know definitely not to do.

### Ah, right... *do something*.

Yes, there's always that urge to Do Something, isn't there?  It's like an *itch*.  They are inflaming the itch with their constant calls and mails, that is the point, to get you to do something, anything, on the hopes that you do something stupid from your ignorance of the system.  *This works.  This makes bank.  That's why they do it.*

Well, you can tell them to **Stop Calling**.  Under FCRA and similar law in most developed countries, they have to stop phoning you after you tell them not to. Don't you dare state anything about the debt.  That's "doing something".

The plain mail letters, throw them in the trash. That's "doing something".

But really, I'm gonna **frame challenge** and say that your precondition of "what do I **DO**" is wrong, because 99.9% of this is resisting the urge to do something.  Resisting is doing something.

Here's something you can positively do.  Let It Go.

### Do the Right Thing

The moral thing is to pay your debts **as agreed, *when agreed***.  Time is of the essence. Once you blow it, you can't use money to go un-blow it.  You can't un-ring that bell, that's a conceit.

The system as-designed *doesn't even want you to try*.  There is simply no moral way to pay money back to a company *this late in the game*. Doing so *does great harm to you* because of a side effect, and that *new harm* is not moral.  I call this "insane" because I don't have time to write a 200,000 word book explaining all the factors and how this has been carefully honed for 400 years amongst competing interests, most of whom are in fact deeply religious. But it has.

It is a conceit that your own morality trumps all: trumps laws of the land, trumps your agreements with others, and most of all, trumps the other person's morality. **That isn't morality, that's hubris**.  In an agreement, *everone* gets a say on what is moral. The industry has a standard for that.

What they want is very rational. Your original creditor wants this incident *behind him*. **And behind you. Forgiveness isn't just Decent, it's good for business**.  They do not want you mired in the weight of debt for decades, because people in bankruptcy don't buy new cars or go to the theater.  That is why the cutoff is 2-7 years. They want you to learn the lessons, get your feet back under you, and come back as a good customer doing profitable business with them.

And that is exactly what you should do.  Remember them and select them preferentially *when you are doing well*.

This is rational.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88645/discussion-on-answer-by-harper-i-co-signed-on-an-apartment-when-i-was-18-with-my).

Comment: Why do you say the boyfriend is the "main debtor"? It says "co-signed"

Comment: "Paying the debt fully.... restarts the clock and gives you 7 years of bad luck on your credit report." Do you have a cite for that?

Comment: @Acccumulation that depends on the creditor willingly consenting to remove the mark from your credit report on exchange for payment, and you successfully holding him to his agreement, and the reporting agency not reporting it anyway.  That is not automatic.  He absolutely can put "R9 paid on full" or "R9 settled less than full bal" and the date is the payoff date and you are stuck with that mark for 7 years *because that is the truth*.

Comment: How does this answer change if we assume OP already *did* acknowledge the debt in the very interaction that lead her to ask this question?

Comment: This seems like the fastest way to get bailiffs breaking into your apartment.  The OP is legally responsible for the debt, as co-signing makes both parties fully responsible for the debt.  The fact that they found her, but not him, does not make her less responsible for the debt.

Worse, there's no reference that the OP has left the property yet...

Comment: @peter I wouldn't assume that because it's unlikely she did.  Acknowledging the debt is more than a slip of a tongue in a phone call.

Comment: @UKMonkey did you read the question? From the ages stated in the first 2 sentences she was with this guy starting 8 years ago and ending 5 years ago. US evictions are much faster than 5 years.  He can no longer be found, so clearly not there. If she was still there, she'd have asked differently.  So obviously neither has been in the apartment for probably 5 years. That's near or past the statute of limitations in most States, which means she is *not* legally responsible for the debt.  I don't like that the system is like this.  But it's like this.

Comment: @Harper did you read the question? At no point did she say that he moved out, or that she moved out.  They can split up and one remain in the house; both remain in the house, or both leave.  Clearly he left - but that doesn't say anything about HER position

Comment: @UKMonkey "it has been in collections **for years**" that would have triggered an eviction, and  in the US those don't take "years". Also if she was still there with him 5 years gone, she would be asking a VERY different question,  and referring to it as "my apartment" and calling herself "the tenant" not "a cosigner".

Comment: Does posting this question, itself, under what looks like it might be a real name, also “acknowledge the debt”?

Comment: @jez that's a good point, maybe OP should change screen name

Comment: Why did you bring religion into your answer?

Comment: @Evorlor because I tried not doing so, and got downvoted for being godless/amoral. Sigh.

Comment: `you can tell them to Stop Calling` - or you can just block their number? doesn't everybody use a smartphone these days? ditto for their email addresses

Comment: Is this answer (and the deadlines) valid word-wide, or only in a specific country? If the latter, could you please include the country, this answer applies to?

Comment: This is a really good answer *except* for the part about "hubris." If you believe something is the morally right thing to do, and the society in which you live *doesn't* (and treats it as such)—it doesn't suddenly stop being morality. That's a pretty harmful claim, and, I believe, the cause of a *lot* of bad action (because "well, other people do it, and it harms me if i didn't do it, _therefore_ me **not** doing it is hubris!") The idea that "industry standard defines morality" is frankly kind of terrifying. :l

Comment: @AmagicalFishy The industry standard doesn't define morality, it defines THEIR morality.  Difference being, they are open and public about it.  *Specifically so that you can decide whether you want to do business with them*. Hubris comes along when you agree to do business with them *and then* try to claim the moral high ground.

Comment: @Nijin22 It is certainly not global advice. In Norway the bad credit is removed immediately upon full repayment of the debt and associated fees. You may therefore want to acknowledge the debt so that you can negotiate a reduction.

Comment: The advice in this answer about not paying or acknowledging the debt is also applicable in Australia, where time limit is 6 years (or 3 years in the NT).

Comment: "There is simply no moral way to pay money back to a company this late in the game" Sorry, how is paying a debt you owe not the moral thing to do? This entire answer is clearly the immoral, albeit questionably legal, thing to do, instead.

Comment: @TylerH if you want to talk about morals, go to the chat.  But I don't decide the morals of the industry, I just tell what they are.  Their morals are you should be punished for an additional 7 years when the law only intends 7 years total, that is not moral either and you need to know about it.  There are other ways to repent.    If you're so up on your high horse that you'll shoot the messenger, I'd say you are in no position to judge others sir.

Comment: @Harper I'm not judging you, just this answer's advice. "Ignore the debt and never pay it" may be legal in that you can avoid legal recourse by somehow avoiding authorities and collectors for seven years (thus not a great suggestion), but certainly the claim that "paying a debt you owe is immoral" is absurd.

Comment: @TylerH You missed the part where I said it's an unrightable wrong and it's vanity to think you can fix it later. What do you propose then, to salve your conscience? Pay the debt to the original creditor? He sold it, for 3 cents on the dollar, to a scummy collection agency. You are trying to be honest *with a system that is utterly corrupt*. He is out 97 cents and it's your fault.  If you pay him 97 cents he is obliged to hand it over to the agency.  **How do you right the wrong sir?**

Comment: Please keep the discussion to the "chat room" https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88645/discussion-on-answer-by-harper-i-co-signed-on-an-apartment-when-i-was-18-with-my :)

Answer (score 78):

After 8 years, you should have a fundamental understanding that things will not change with this ex-boyfriend.  He may not be found, and even if he is, he will not pay any portion.  Dragging him through some legal process will cause you to spend money and emotional capital for something that will yield no result.  It is a complete waste of time.

So really you have two choices.  The first is to pay the bills.  Use typical collection clearing tactics.  Negotiate what you owe down, make a lump sum payment using a throw away debit card or money order, and have it in writing that the bill is satisfied.  Never make payments, never give them access to your checking account.  Once that is done you can move on with your life and do great things.  This will be a necessary step if you want to buy a home.

The second is to ignore the collectors.  From the way that you ask the question this is your option right now.  If I woke up in your shoes, I would concentrate on how I can earn more money to get this debt (and any other debt) cleared.  Until you have some cash, ready to pay these bills off, just earn.

This is a hurt that keeps on giving and echos into your future.  The sooner you can get this behind you the better.  It will be futile to get this dead beat to pay any portion of what he owes.  Please learn from this mistake and try not to repeat it in the future.  As gnasher said, the answer to every cosign question is "No".  Also, take it a step further, never ask a loved one to cosign for you if you value the relationship.

**Edit:**
There is another option here.  You could negotiate with the creditors to remove your name from the lien.  Lets say that the creditors say that the amount owed is $1,500.  You can say, I will give you $300 if you remove my name from the lien.  You can still try and collect from Mr. Deadbeat the full amount, but just take my name off the lien.  Again make sure you get this all in writing.  They might just go for some deal like that.

Additionally there is some avocation of allowing the debt to "age out".  In some cases this works, but debt collectors are good at preventing this from happening.  All they have to do is resell the debt to someone else and the clock starts again.
There is nothing stopping a debt collector owner from opening two companies.  When debts come close to aging out, he just sells it to his other company.  The portfolio does not change, nothing is lost, and the debt is never aged out.

Relying on debts aging out is a pipe dream that will never happen.

Comment: The legal process depends much on the circumstances. If he is absolutely broke, then it's pointless. But if he has some money it might be worth it.

Comment: A "legal" process here is utterly, totally worthless.

Comment: @Fattie I disagree, it depends on the circumstances. And on the legal system. For example where I live, a beatiful and truely great country named switzerland, you can legally persue someone who is owning you money. You then have the option to settle this privately before you go to court. If you can prove that he own you someting which is not that difficult you can in fact seize a portion of their income until the debt is paid off. So it very much depends on the circumstances.

Comment: Ah - of course what you say is correct @LucasRaphaelPianegonda . But this question is in the USA.  As you say it depends on circumstances and jurisdiction.  Very unfortunately in this specific QA, a legal process here is utterly, totally worthless.

Comment: @Fattie: Where does it say that this is in the USA?

Comment: @LucasRaphaelPianegonda *"you can legally persue someone who is owning you money"* That's exactly what's happening here. The problem is that the asker is the one who owes money, and they are now being legally pursued by the people that it is owed to. By co-signing, they became jointly liable for the rent. The ex-boyfriend doesn't owe them anything; the two of them together owe the landlord.

Comment: @anaximander The question at hand is then if the ex owes her anything?

Comment: @LucasRaphaelPianegonda And the simple answer, from the information presented, is that he doesn't. Contracts like this simply state that the landlord must be paid the full amount by the tenants; they don't (usually) make any stipulation of which tenant pays what. If the landlord cannot contact some of the tenants, then they are free to pursue whichever ones they can find for the full sum, which is what is happening here. The contract would have said this is how it works, and *the asker signed it*. That's going to be very difficult to get out of.

Comment: @anaximander The ex likely *could* owe the asker money, if the asker has paid a disproportionate amount of the rent to date, and especially if the asker pays off the entire remaining balance. I do agree, however, that pursuing this legally is probably not worthwhile. The ex seems unlikely to pay, no matter what, and suing would cost money in itself. For LucasRaphaelPianegonda, the issue is practical, not legal or moral.

Comment: @Upper_Case Unfortunately, it's not common for contracts to say anything about fair apportionment of liability; ethically and practically, the ex-boyfriend might owe them something, but legally speaking, paying a disproportionate amount of the rent is not something that the contract makes any stipulations about. There you'd be into the realms of verbal or implied agreements, which is not a great foundation for a lawsuit; particularly not for one that's cheap to pursue or quick to resolve, even when you can actually find the person you're suing.

Comment: @anaximander I was referring only to a plausible civil suit initiated by the asker, in which it is likely (though of course not guaranteed) that the outcome would be >$0. It is completely separate from the lease agreement and unrelated to the former landlord or current collection agency, and as above it is almost certainly not worthwhile for the asker to pursue.

Comment: @Upper_Case but in that case, the dispute (paying too much share of rent) will have the same or shorter statute of limitations than the current collection action.  Demanding equity *now* after so long will be a little hard to explain.

Comment: @LucasRaphaelPianegonda *"you can legally persue someone who is owning you money"*. The problem is, he doesn't owe her anything. Co-signing is essentially a contract saying that *if the other party cannot pay, you will assume full responsibility* so that the provider of the loan is guaranteed to get their money back. Unless they had a separate contract breaking down the cost sharing between the two, OP is screwed.

Comment: @Harper Not if the asker pays off the remaining balance *now*, after (presumably) years of fruitless efforts getting the ex to pay more than $0 of the outstanding balance. In any event, I cannot emphasize enough that I *do not recommend* pursuing the ex for payment. Even under ideal circumstances it would be a gamble, and this situation is not ideal. I am only trying to clarify that seeking money from the ex through the legal system is a bad idea due to practical issues, not because it's legally impossible or the asker has no official recourse.

Comment: `As gnasher said, the answer to every cosign question is "No" ` While good advice this is largely impossible in practice. I have never encountered a shared living situation where the landlord was willing to accept non-family tenants that are not all signatories to the lease. Unless you have the financial resources to pass credit and income checks for housing on your own and are able to negotiate with the landlord to allow subleasing you are SOL. That being said, once someone leaves the lease should be resigned, there should be no reason to remain liable for housing you don't live in.

Comment: @AlexandreAubrey As far as the bank is concerned, they both owe the bank money and they are both in trouble if the bank doesn't get the money. That doesn't mean there isn't a separate contract between the two of them, where he is supposed to pay all the money.

Comment: Reselling a debt does not reset the clock. Unscrupulous debt collectors will report it to credit bureaus as if it were reset, and/or will tell the debtor that it was reset. But from a legal standpoint, it was not! And those unscrupulous collectors can get sued into oblivion. Maybe that's when the second agency comes in - when the first one gets sued, it closes shop, and the second one takes over?

Comment: YM 'advocacy' not 'avocation' (which is a hobby or pastime; a=not + vocation=work/profession)

Answer (score 16):

Joint and several liability means they will go for the person that has the most assets or is easier to trace.

It would appear that you are way past the statute of limitations for most states (e.g. six years for New York) and unless you make any agreement with a debit collector, which starts the timeline again from that date, they shouldn't be able to pursue you any further for recovery. It will have a negative impact on your credit rating for a while, but then paying them in full would still have the same impact.

Comment: +1 for noticing the statute.  But an agreement can be mere acknowledgement of the debt, a meeting of the minds on that subject.

Comment: Indeed! Important to tell debt collectors to make all requests in writing and not make spur of the moment comments to them that will come back and bite you. Also important to note that when the primary debt collector gives in it will generally get passed down (sold) to the bottom-feeders in the form of an Excel sheet and they tend to blur the rules slightly :-)

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I can give you from the information I have is:

## 1 Locate him

His address, his workplace, his phone number - those things help.

## 2 Get a legal advisor

Someone familiar with your local law should be consulted. I know those people are expensive but legal advice can be cheaper than paying all the rent yourself. Ask him if you can get out of the apartment contract somehow, and ask him if your ex is liable and how much he owes you. He might also be able to help you locate your ex.

## 3 Send him an ultimatum

Send him a letter (best with a registered letter, so he is not able to deny that he got the letter) with a neat summary of what you payed or will pay and what he is supposed to pay. Make a suggestion on what his monthly payment should be. If he starts to negotiate that would be good, so don't immediately refuse it. But don't let him screw you over. Make it absolutely clear that if he doesn't pay legal steps will be taken. Write it formally correct, be polite and send a copy to yourself which you don't open (evidence for later steps).

## 4 Sue him

If nothing helps, he still refuses and your legal advisor thinks you'll have a chance, then sue him. Most of the times this will do the trick and he will start to negotiate and will pay his part. If not you'll get it by force in front of a judge. Legal steps are not to be taken lightly but in a case like that it usually pays off since a few years of rent is a lot of money.

**Edit:** Depending on the circumstances namely the specific law, the evidence you have at hand for his debt to you and his/your financial situation this is more or less likely to work out. **There is also the option of writing the hole thing off and pay the debt yourself**, which I only didn't include in the initial answer because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This won't work because there is nothing in law that says a cosigner owes the other cosigner any money. The cosignatories are "joint and severally" liable. The lender can choose to recover the whole amount from one individual. Privately suing a deadbeat with no assets on the basis of, at best, a verbal agreement is likely to cost more than would be recoverable in many cases.

Comment: Finding the other tenant and getting legal advice is good. Sending him an ultimatum of sorts might help, depending on exactly what it says, but the legal advice you get in step 2 should help you work that out. That last part, though... The asker *signed a contract* stating that *they would pay* if the other tenant didn't. I really doubt a lawsuit will get them out of that.

Comment: OP has no cause for action against the ex boyfriend, he doesn't owe ***her*** any money.  What's more, suing will acknowledge the debt, restarting the statute of limitations for her and not him LOL.

Comment: Usually, ultimatums are issued from a position of power.

Comment: Not a lawyer, but I imagine that *if* she paid the debt, *and* they had a verbal agreement for him to pay all the rent, she would have a valid reason to sue him to recover that money. Of course, we all know verbal agreements are worth the paper they're printed on, unless he's stupid enough to acknowledge it.

Answer (score 0):

> What can be done in this situation?

Three options:

1.
The best plan is for you to <del>pay the money</del> settle<sup>1</sup> the debt.
Some people call things like this that they've done in their own past a "stupid tax" meaning that it is a tax (something that you have to pay but don't want to) on the thing they did which they (in hindsight) think was stupid of them to do.
We all have decisions we've made which we look back on and say, "That was a bad choice!"

2.
Continue as you are - don't pay them and keep being harassed.

3.
If you really have both no money and no assets, you can file for bankruptcy protection.
Save up about $500 and file it - you'll be no worse off than you are now.
Note that you may not qualify for bankruptcy, or if you do the court may decide that this is a affordable debt for you and require that you pay it.

> Is he liable for the rent?

Based on what you said, sounds like he is.

> And how am I able to get him to pay?

Well, you can't.
Based on what you've said he has no intention of paying.

Come on! Is there *really* nothing I can do?

Okay, you *could* get a judgement against him for his share of the problem **if** the statute of limitations hasn't run out.  You could *if* you had money for a lawyer, but you don't.  And you'd need good records for this to work - like all your canceled checks (which you either paid to him or to the rental agent/company).

---

<sup>1</sup> by "pay the money" I meant "settle the debt" (in full).
I did not say or mean to imply that she should make payments.

Comment: Paying the money Will restart the statute of limitations and restart the 7 year aging on her credit report.  Filing for bankruptcy is unhelpful if you have no assets and won't soon, because it creates a new 10-year burn on your credit report.  That's worse.  For a time-barred debt, bankruptcy is probably not even possible.  Also, you are repeating the trope that cosigners can sue each other.  They can't.

Comment: This answer is crazy! *Definitely do not pay the debt.* Check Harper's answer for some realistic, good advice.

Comment: @Harper You're correct, but the question was "what can be done." I saw three options and listed all three. The OP is posting questions here, so I assume one day she will have assets. While the debt may not be on her credit report any more, unless there is a statute of limitations on it (and there may not be, or it may be really long) it will still be out there for her to be sued under unless it is either settled or released by bankruptcy.

Answer (score 0):

> I co-signed on an apartment with my ex-boyfriend when I was 18 and he was 21. We broke up.

That sucks. Why didn't you get rid of the apartment back then?

> What can be done in this situation?

Co-signing is like saying "if he doesn't pay I promise I'll pay in his place". So the collector doesn't care whether it's you who pays or him. Their only concern is getting the money with the least effort. If it's easier to get it from you, they'll get it from you. From their point of view there is no such thing as "he is liable for half, she is liable for the other half" (unless it was specifically in the contract). The collector will not stop trying to get the money from you.

The most productive thing you can do is try really hard to find the boyfriend and convince him to pay (assuming he's not broke like you). If you find him but fail to convince him, you can pass his info to the collector and then the collector will at least be going after him as much as you. The collector might also find him on their own. I'm sure neither of you wants to foot the bill for the other person, nor does the collector want to waste their time on this indefinitely, so hopefully you can come to an agreement where you both pay your equal share and be done with the thing.

If you simply can't get a hold of the boyfriend no matter what, you are basically stuck with the entire amount. You'll just have to pay it off. If you are truly unable to, you could declare bankruptcy, in which case the bills will go away but so will your assets and credit. Bankruptcy should probably be your last resort. You could also ghost the collector like some suggest and hope they will give up. I doubt this will work - the collector pays money for the right to collect the debt. So if they gave up easily, they would go out of business.

Suing might be an option, but the biggest problem is that as I said, you agreed to all this when co-signing, so it's hard to argue there's an injustice. Maybe you feel it's unjust that he gets to disappear and leave you with the bill, but you were assumed to have considered that possibility when co-signing. But in your jurisdiction, there might nevertheless be laws that allow you to demand restitution. In some places co-habiting like this can afford you protections similar to marriage. If you want to try that, you should go to a lawyer. The lawyer will also advice on how to sue a person you can't find. He could also give you better advice on your legal liabilities regarding the bills. So you want to look for one specializing in debts and/or domestic law and see if they do free consultations.